# How can I change wifi state by android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-wifi

I am trying to change wi-fi state by using my android application. I have used CHANGE_WIFI_STATE and ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

And I have used the following code to change the wi-fi status.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn_wifi_on, btn_wifi_off;
    WifiManager wifiManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_wifi_on = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTurnOn);
        btn_wifi_off = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTurnOff);

        btn_wifi_on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                assert wifiManager != null;
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wifi Turned on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        btn_wifi_off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                assert wifiManager != null;
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wifi Turned off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

When I click the button only Toast message is appearing, but the wi-fi status is not changing.

Can anyone help what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't really seem to have any problem but here's an optimised approach with few lines of code

```
WifiManager wifiManager;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
  }

  public void startService(View v) {
    if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
      wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
      Toast.makeText(this, "WiFi Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
      wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
      Toast.makeText(this, "WiFi Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
```